# Javascript Date object wrong for January 1, 1980

Tags: javascript

When I convert a string date to a date object, it's getting the date wrong:

```js
function formatDate(inputDateString) {
    const date = new Date(inputDateString);
            
    // Check if the date is valid
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
        return "Invalid Date";
    }

    const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); // Adding 1 because months are zero-based
    const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
}

var testDate = formatDate("1980-01-01");
console.log("testDate: " + testDate);
```

**Result: 12/31/1979**

At first I thought maybe my `getXXX()` constructions were suspect, but in Chrome Dev Tools, the debugger is telling me that the moment I create the `new Date()` object, it believes the date is 12/31/1979. I'm wondering about GMT/UTC type of stuff, but I believe that js date functions already take into account user's time zone. I am in Mountain Time.

WTH?

Comment: it logs `testDate: 01/01/1980`

Comment: It depends on where you are located on the planet. Your local time zone is used to show the date, but UTC is used to construct the date.

Comment: Also you are not hours *later* than UTC, you are hours *earlier*. The earth rotates from west to east.

Comment: How can I change my function so that it works with user's current time zone?

Comment: If you use an online converter to epoch (i.e. https://www.epochconverter.com/) and you use `date.getTime()` with the given date (1980-01-01) - you'll notice that in your timezone, you are 6 hours behind midnight (ie. the day before) - your results will change if you wait 6 hours :)

Comment: Passing in a single string will result in UTC time, passing in: year, month, day will give you local time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Comment: It would have been obvious just by log output that something is with the time zone, the time difference is only 1 day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript's Date object indeed considers time zones when interpreting date strings. When you pass a date string in the format YYYY-MM-DD (like "1980-01-01"), JavaScript interprets it as a date in the UTC time zone. If you're in Mountain Time (MST/MDT), that's either 6 hours (MDT) or 7 hours (MST) behind UTC.

So when you create a new date with the string "1980-01-01", it's assuming midnight at the start of that day in UTC. When you view that same point in time in MST, it's still the previous day – specifically, 5pm (or 4pm in MDT) on 12/31/1979.

**Use the Date constructor that takes the year, month, and day as arguments**: This always assumes the date is in the local time zone:

```
const date = new Date(1980, 0, 1); // remember, months are 0-based
```

Comment: `// remember, months are 0-based` this always fools me, I read it is somehow a "port" from C, but I still think whoever programmed that was on LSD